# set bit "setuid" for file and store changes on repositroy by using git

Tags: linux, git, attributes

I have a git repository and I need to set setuid by using "chmod 6775" for one of files and then commit changes.

But these changes do not present when I download that repository to another host. I do not see "S" or "s" sign in attributes:

```
After commit: 
-rwsrwsr-x  1 root stuff  51804 Apr 13 18:05 cli-0-38

After download: 

-rwxrwxr-x  1 root stuff  51804 Apr 13 18:05 cli-0-38
```

Could you please advice how to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git (unfortunately) does not track full filemodes. It only tracks the executable bit, and even for that, it only tracks a single bit for the whole file, not per-user/group/other. So you won't be able to use git to track this setting.

One way to get around this, for example, is to write a small "setup.sh" shell script where you store the various "chmod u+s filename" operations, and run that script after doing a new clone or pull.

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately, I'll have to edit Salt and CFeng configs in this case to overcome it.

Comment: Tracking permissions that finely would be a bug, not a feature. In fact, it *was* a "feature" in early Git (and removed later), but as a result `git fsck` allows blob objects to have mode `664`, with group-write permission, as well as `644`, without it. This allows the use of repositories made back when it was thought to be a feature.

Answer (score 1):

It your `.git` folder you should see a config.
Looking something like this;

> [core]
>
> filemode = false

If that is so change it to true rather than false or you can use;

> git config core.filemode true

Comment: [core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true was previously set there.

Comment: Well i dont know sorry. Good luck getting help!